# Height issue with Facebook Embed Post

Tags: facebook, height, embed

I am using the FB Post Embed. On initial load the posts are shown up. But if I add a new post and then call an ajax postback, after postback all the posts are not shown.I checked the documentation it mentioned to call FB.XFBML.parse() method, i called that but it still didn't work. While looking into the the code I saw that the height and width of the span that FB returns back and iframe inside the span is set to 0 and overflow hidden. The fb:post code is shown up here:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. The issue was that I have kept the inside my container div tag using $("#container").prepend("");. The container div tag was getting emptied and refilled using $("#container").empty();, that's why the height width were getting 0. I updated the code to keep the fb-root outside of the container using $("#container").parent().prepend("");